# Toggling Map View from Full Screen to small thumbnail show the location

Tags: android, maps

I m trying to integrate a map view as in "Zomato.com" app.in a android.

Where the map is shown in a small area in the restaurant details screen. It displays a small strip like map area in the bottom of the screen. Clicking on that opens the map in full view and with a close button there. will take it back to the same position. Can you please let me know if you have any library functions or customisation can be done ?

Comment: did you manage to get a way of doing this ?